# Reading from the serial port with the DataReceived event

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C# .net 2.0 CF application that reads from a serial port using the `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` class. Unfortunately, the `SerialDataReceivedEventHandler` is never called.

I open the port like this:

```
private SerialPort serial_port_;
protected void OpenSerialPort(string port, int baud)
{
    if (serial_port_ == null)
    {
        serial_port_ = new SerialPort(port,
                                  baud,
                                  Parity.None,
                                  8,
                                  StopBits.One);
    }
    else
    {
        serial_port_.BaudRate = baud;
        serial_port_.PortName = port;
    }

    if (!serial_port_.IsOpen)
    {
        serial_port_.Open();
        serial_port_.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(OnSerialDataReceived);
    }
}

private void OnSerialDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Serial data received");
}
```

If, however, I add a `Debug.WriteLine(serial_port_.ReadLine());` right after the port is opened, I see in the output window a line of text from the port just as I would expect.

So, why does `ReadLine` work, but the `DataReceived` event does not?

Thanks,
PaulH

---

**Edit:** Further testing shows this code works on some devices, but not others. What does the `DataReceived` event require to work properly?

**Further Frustration:** On this device, `ReadExisting` always returns null and `BytesToRead` always returns 0. 
`ReadLine()` and `Read()` both work perfectly, though.

Comment: @zsalzbank - yes. fixed the typo

Comment: what does `OnSerialDataReceived` look like?

Comment: @zsalzbank - I've added it to the code above.

Comment: try setting DtrEnable and RtsEnable to true

Comment: Does the device attached to the serial port send lines periodically?

Comment: @zsalzbank - setting DtrEnable and RtsEnable to true made no difference.

Comment: @dbasnett - Yes, it is a GPS device and I'm reading NMEA lines. If I just put a `ReadLine` in a loop, it will continue to show new data though the `DataReceived` event never fires. (obviously, I mean that the event doesn't fire even when I do not have the ReadLine in a loop).

Comment: Try adding the event handler before you open the port.  My GPS device, when in NMEA mode, outputs data constantly after it is opened.  If yours is like mine the event handler should fire without any explicit reads.  Make certain that the ports .ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1.  Make certain that the handler is actually added.  In the code above it won't be if the port is open.

Comment: @dbasnett - I've verified by stepping through the code that the event handler is added and the port is opened. Though it should be set by default, I've tried your suggestion of explicitly setting `ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1`, it did not have any effect. Nor did moving the event handler assignment before the `Open` call.

Comment: Is it still true that if you put a read after the open you see data?  Very strange.

Comment: I found this thread which sounds like your problem.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/542b74c4-1514-4488-96f0-863ccd4c67f3/

Comment: @dbasnett - Yes, a Read() or ReadLine() call will still show serial data correctly.. It looks like the two issues in that thread were DtrEnable (which we already tried) and that he was trying to update a control from outside the GUI thread (which I am not doing).

Comment: As a work-around, I've switch to calling `SerialPort.Read` from a thread. It's sub-optimal, but functional.

Comment: You might want to post your problem at https://connect.microsoft.com/ in case it is a bug.  Glad you have a fix.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put blocking reads in the data received handler.  If the handler fires and there is NOT an entire **line** to be read it will block.  In the code you posted there is not a read of any kind.

From MSDN: "PinChanged , DataReceived, and ErrorReceived events may be called out of order, and there may be a slight delay between when the underlying stream reports the error and when the event handler is executed. **Only one event handler can execute at a time.**"

Comment: There isn't any read of any kind in the handler in the code the OP posted.  I assumed that he moved the readline to the handler.

Comment: I did have it there at one time, so I'm glad you posted that. But, I have it commented out (and will remove it). At the moment, I'm just trying to get a `DataReceived` event.